# How to import a .txt file with a desired structure

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, text

I need to import a txt file which was supossed to be X rows with 18 columns each but actually is like this (even though cannot be seen every 13 columns starts a new line of just 5 elements):

2.0462020e+001  2.9598587e+001  2.8684617e+001  1.2745371e+001  2.3967345e+001  2.4593504e+001  1.2683864e+001  3.1394543e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000

8.8575460e-001  1.0210176e+000  1.2740904e+000  1.3526302e+000  1.4878932e+000  1.8107791e+000  1.9067722e+000  2.8143434e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000  0.0000000e+000

The call `feat = np.loadtxt(x)`
returns a strange dimension (3, 602014) and if I analyze row 0 for example it starts like:
1.0 20.46 29.58 28.68 12.74 23.96 24.59 12.683.12 2.0 20.46 29.58 ...
It is like for the first row in the result I get all the non 0 values for the columns of the real dataset 0,3,6,9,12 ...
In the 2n row I would have the same but for original lines 1,4,7,... and again the structure is the same, starts with 1.0 + values!=0 of 1st line + 2.0 + values!= 4th line.

As I said, I would like to get an array of dimension (X, 18) without the 1.0 and 2.0 that are appearing and where X is just the numbers of rows the original file was suppose to had (every 18 columns a new row)

The file can be downloaded in https://github.com/OpenSLAM-org/openslam_ufastslam/blob/master/code/victoria_park/landmark.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `genfromtxt` (or `loadtxt`) I get:

```
In [64]: data = np.genfromtxt('../Downloads/landmark.txt')
In [65]: data.shape
Out[65]: (3, 60204)
In [66]: data.dtype
Out[66]: dtype('float64')
In [67]: data[0,:10]
Out[67]: 
array([ 1.       , 20.46202  , 29.598587 , 28.684617 , 12.745371 ,
       23.967345 , 24.593504 , 12.683864 ,  3.1394543,  2.       ])
In [68]: data[1,:10]
Out[68]: 
array([1.       , 0.8857546, 1.0210176, 1.2740904, 1.3526302, 1.4878932,
       1.8107791, 1.9067722, 2.8143434, 2.       ])
```

This matches what I see when I look at the file in my text editor - 3 lines with many columns.

`data.reshape(-1,18)` produces an array with `(10034, 18)`.  We could drop the initial `1.000`, but that would mess up the reshape (no long a multiple of 18).

Answer (score 1):

Your text file is only 4 rows long with thousands of columns.  I think if we read the entire file in and get rid of the newlines we can create a single list of values.

Then we can make that a numpy array and rehsape it.

```
import numpy as np
with open('landmark.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    data=myfile.read().replace('\n', '').split()

my_data = np.array(data).reshape((int(len(data)/18), 18))
```